# BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'search'

Tags: python, html, flask

App.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="." method="post">
        Search: <input type="text" name="search">
        <input type="submit" value="Show">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/CmpPr')
def cmpP():
    return render_template('CmpPr.html')

@app.route('/CmpSpes')
def cmpS():
    return render_template('CmpSpes.html')

@app.route('/App', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def App():
    search = request.form['search']
    return render_template('output.html', n=search)

@app.route('/Gro')
def Gro():
    return render_template('Gro.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

I have created multiple html pages

I want to print the message, request from TextBox(above code) and print to another html page

I tried using request.form.get('search') but its returning null

And if I use request.form.get('search', FALSE or TRUE) it returns FALSE or TRUE

I have also used if else loop to specify GET and POST method, still it shows the same error

Can anyone please help me on this

Thank You

Comment: Looks like `<form action="."` should be `<form action="/App"`

Comment: Thank You sir I have also tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your form action should point to the view that handle the form data (i.e. `/App`):

```
<form action="/App" method="post">
```

Secondly, you should only obtain the form data when the request's method is `POST`, since you have set `method="post"` in the template. Also, you will need to render the App.html that contains the form when request method is `GET`:

```py
@app.route('/App', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def App():
    if request.method == 'POST':  # get form data when method is POST
        search = request.form['search']
        return render_template('output.html', n=search)
    return render_template('App.html')  # when the method is GET, it will render App.html
```

P.S. The error you got is explained clearly that there isn't a key called `search` in the form data.

Comment: You are welcome, please accept this answer if you think it's useful.